# Tableau is counting too many records

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau and not sure what information is needed to answer this question.
I have set up my Data Source with multiple tables and joins.  All of the joins are inner joins.
I am trying to get a count of records from one of my tables.
The table has 112,000 records but tableau is returning a count of 12 million

Comment: Even an inner join can cause a 1-to-many mapping if you don't specify enough fields to join on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your joins is multiplying the record count by 10. I suggest removing the joins 1 by 1 until you pinpoint the cause.